# Get users by 'createdTimestamp' in Keycloak admin client Node JS

Tags: node.js, keycloak

I am trying to delete users created before a certain time using Keycloak Admin Client in Node.js

I am able to get users by username, firstName, lastName with a command like this:

`const users = await keycloak.users.find({ username: 'rc' })`

Users have a `createdTimestamp` attribute, but when I try to find someone by it, e.g.

`const users = await keycloak.users.find({ createdTimestamp: 1640191005096 })`

then it just returns all users.

Users look like this:

```json
{
    id: 'd0ff32e5-7604-4d07-8067-ded2d96a608d',
    createdTimestamp: 1640191005096,
    username: 'rc',
    enabled: true,
    totp: false,
    emailVerified: true,
    firstName: 'rocket',
    lastName: 'example',
    email: 'example@example.com',
    disableableCredentialTypes: [],
    requiredActions: [],
    notBefore: 0,
    access: {
      manageGroupMembership: true,
      view: true,
      mapRoles: true,
      impersonate: true,
      manage: true
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround that I am using for this is to find all account and then access the `createdTimestap` by doing `.createdTimestamp`:

```js
    const users = await keycloak.users.find()
    for (const [i, user] of users.entries()) {
      if (user.createdTimestamp < dateToTimestamp) {
        deletedUsers.push(user.username)
        deletedIDs.push(user.id)
        await keycloak.users.del({ id: user.id });
        console.info(`Account with username: ${deletedUsers[i]} and ID: ${deletedIDs[i]} has been deleted from Keycloak`)
      } 
    }
```

Didn't take a lot of extra effort.

Comment: How can i list more than 100 users using the find() method ??

Comment: @JagadeeshKumarCK you will have to pass attributes. const users = await keycloak.users.find({max: 200});

Comment: Is there a way to get the result only with needed fields like firstName, lastName and email in the find() method?

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately not possible

The corresponding keycloak api endpoint does only allow to search for

- email
- username
- firstName
- lastName

see https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/index.html#_getusers

The only possible solution for you is to load all users and filter/search for `createdTimestamp` on the client side.
But this highly depends on how many users you have in your realm. If there are many, this solution is probably too slow/not performant enough for you.

Comment: Thanks, I have posted my answer below in case anyone needs an example.